# Raspberry Pi backup server (windows & mac)

Tags: raspbian, linux, backup, partition

I would like to set up my raspberry pi model B and my 2TB hard drive as a backup server for both my windows pc and my mac. I would like to partition my hard drive such that 300GB is for mac time machine backups, 300GB is for windows backup image and the remaining space is a partition to be used for file sharing.

Pi is running Raspbian OS

Can anyone guide me on how to go about partitioning my drive with my Pi?

Been following this [guide](https://raymii.org/s/articles/Build_a_35_dollar_Time_Capsule_-_Raspberry_Pi_Time_Machine.html) (but it doesnt fit my needs anymore).

Comment: It is unclear from your post exactly what you are asking. I was about to recommend `netatalk`, but the guide mentions this. If all you are asking is how to make a smaller partition you would just need to modify `mkpart primary 2048s 100%` Read the `parted` man page for details.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use GParted for creating the partitions on you hard drive. Or, you can use the gnome-disk-utility, is useful for managing mounted drives like hard drives, usb memory stick etc. And this tool is really simple to use for creating partitions.

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/admin/gnome-disk-utility

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone guide me on how to go about partitioning my drive with my Pi?

Tools that will we be available on most Linux systems, and therefore also on the typical Pi distributions, are `sfdisk`, `parted` or the original `fdisk`. All are tools for disk partitioning and partition resizing.